# Calling window.onload inside a cshtml view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to call a window.onload function inside a cshtml view.

My code looks like this.

```
@model BusinessModel
    @if(Model.Business != null)
    {
        <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            if ('@Model.Business'!='') {
                var data = {
                //JSON Object
                };
                
                $.ajax({
                url: www.google.com,
                method: 'POST',
                headers:{},
                data : JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (response){
                window.location.replace(new url);
                }
                
                });
                
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>
    } else {
         // Some basic HTML code
    }
```

When i am trying to do something like this, when the condition matches it is never hitting the window.onload function.

Am i doing something wrong or Does this need to be handled in a different way?
Please help me with this

Thanks.

Comment: Is this code successfully emitted to the browser?  What is the actual client-side code observed in the browser?  When in the context of the page is this emitted?  Is this part of the initial page render or is it dynamically added to the page at a later time?

Comment: This code is successfully emitted to web browser, This is not an initial page rendering but when a user opts a selection then the user is redirect to the same page where it will check for condition and render diff content on to the same page.

Comment: *"This is not an initial page rendering"* - So then this JavaScript code is part of an AJAX response and you want the page to execute it when it's injected into the DOM?  How are you fetching this content and how are you adding it to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if `Model.Business` is null in js.Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class BusinessModel
    {
        public List<Business> Business { get; set; }
       
    }
```

Action:

```
public IActionResult Test1()
        {
            var model = new BusinessModel { Business = new List<Business>() };
            return View(model);

        }
```

View:

```
@model BusinessModel
@if (Model.Business == null)
{
    <h1>null</h1>
    // Some basic HTML code
}
<script>

        window.onload = function () {
            if ('@Model.Business'!='') {
                alert("Hello");
            }
        }

    </script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: That works fine, but if i do something like below It doen't work                           
     <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            if ('@Model.Business'!='') {
                var data = {
    //JSON Object
    };
    
    $.ajax({
    url: www.google.com,
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{},
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function (response){
    window.location.replace(new url);
    }
    
    });
    
    return false;
            }
        }

    </script>

Comment: Updated my code, please check

Comment: Do you have any error in Console,I debug and it will go to `window.onload`?Can you ajax post data successfully?